# Kotlin - unresolved reference - factorial

Tags: kotlin

I started with Kotlin an tried a first little "project". Now i get this error:
"Fakultaet.kt:4:10: error: unresolved reference: fakultaet"

What am I doing wrong?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){

    if(args.size ==1 && args[0].toIntOrNull() != null) {
        println(fakultaet(args[0].toInt()))
    } else {
        println("Bitte Ganzzahl als Parameter eingeben")
    }

    fun fakultaet(value: Int): Int {
        var zaehler = 2
        var ergebnis = 1
        val fakultaetVon = value
    
        while(zaehler <= fakultaetVon) {
            ergebnis = ergebnis * zaehler
            zaehler = zaehler + 1
        }   

        return ergebnis
    }
}
```

It should give me the factorial of a number passed as a parameter

Comment: Does it eork if you define the `fakultaet` function before the code using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, you should define the `fakultaet function` outside of the main function, at the top level of your file. Here's your modified code:

```
fun fakultaet(value: Int): Int {
    var zaehler = 2
    var ergebnis = 1
    val fakultaetVon = value

    while (zaehler <= fakultaetVon) {
        ergebnis *= zaehler
        zaehler++
    }

    return ergebnis
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    if (args.size == 1 && args[0].toIntOrNull() != null) {
        println(fakultaet(args[0].toInt()))
    } else {
        println("Bitte Ganzzahl als Parameter eingeben")
    }
}
```

By moving the function to the top level, it becomes accessible to the main function, and your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write your function outside the main one.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){

    if(args.size ==1 && args[0].toIntOrNull() != null){
        println(fakultaet(args[0].toInt()))
    }else{
        println("Bitte Ganzzahl als Parameter eingeben")
    }
}
fun fakultaet(value: Int) :Int{
    var zaehler = 2
    var ergebnis = 1
    val fakultaetVon = value
    
    while(zaehler <= fakultaetVon){
        ergebnis = ergebnis * zaehler
        zaehler = zaehler + 1
    }   

    return ergebnis
}
```

Comment: Technically you don't *have to*, but when using local functions, they should be declared before usage.